# Updating multiple fields when changing one word in string?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Usually I would post code, but this time I have no true idea of where to start or I might just be over complicating a simple issue.

**QUESTION**

So I have a table that stores URL paths as strings

`(Example: 192.168.x.x\Location\Location2\SPECIALNAME\Folder\Folder2)`

and this is allowing us to build a folder/file repository on the client end for our users to add files and access files.

My question is how I would go about updating all fields associated with those that match

`"\SPECIALNAME\"` and replace `'SPECIALNAME'` with another value (if the person changes the name of the main folder, then all subfolders and things linked to this folder should be updated with the new name)

To try and make this more clear of a question:

If my locations are stored in my table:

```
URL\ **SPECIALNAME** \FOLDER\SUBFOLDER

   URL\ **SPECIALNAME** \FOLDER\SUBFOLDER\SUBSUBFOLDER1

   URL\ **SPECIALNAME** \FOLDER\SUBFOLDER2

   URL\ **SPECIALNAME** \FOLDER\SUBFOLDER2\SUBSUBFOLDER1\SUBSUBFOLDER2

   URL\ **SPECIALNAME** \FOLDER\OTHERFOLDER
```

I want to specifically update the field where SPECIALNAME is with the new name that the user might change it to.

*This update statement will probably be doing batches of 80+ updates upon a single name change to give a perspective of how many URL paths will be updated with the new name*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UPDATE table SET url = REPLACE(url, '\\SPECIALNAME\\', '\\MORESPECIALNAME\\') WHERE url LIKE '%\\SPECIALNAME\\%';
```

Comment: Might consider adding slashes so it doesn't match parts of files... but this is the answer.

Comment: @JohnChrysostom Good call. Edited.

Comment: I was considering this and wasn't sure if it was going to update an entire path with NEWNAME or just the specific section.

Seems I should start going with hunches haha, accepting this! Thank you both :)

Answer (score 1):

To start with the query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tablename
WHERE path LIKE "%SPECIALNAME%"
```

Then you can loop through the results and

```
$newPath = STR_replace("SPECIALNAME", "NEWNAME", $query['path']);
```

Comment: Could you expand more on what is happening in the code? I can understand SPECIALNAME being replaced with NEWNAME, but the $query['path'] I've personally never seen done and it looks very interesting :)

Comment: I think he actually wants to update the table with an SQL query. This does not do that.

Comment: `$query['path'])` is PHP. I could have sworn this was tagged with php, but you are right @JohnChrysostom.

Comment: Yeah, someone answered above :) I love PhP and I read it like reading a book without thinking much of it. SIGH, I need to step away from all this server coding haha